# fresh installation of Typo3 10.4.12 doesn't start

Tags: php, typo3-10.x

I am using Server 2019 and IIS.

I have no  problems with Typo3 V9.x but I can't get working V10.4.

Oops, an error occured!

The system started to create the typo3temp and in the log file I got:

```
Sun, 07 Feb 2021 17:18:55 +0100 [CRITICAL] request="09079c2480672" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1203699034: A cache with identifier "cache_core" does not exist. | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Exception\NoSuchCacheException thrown in file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Cache\CacheManager.php in line 138. Requested URL: https://v10.althoff-fam.de/ - {"TYPO3_MODE":"FE","exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Exception\\NoSuchCacheException: A cache with identifier \"cache_core\" does not exist. in C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Cache\\CacheManager.php:138\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\typo3\\sysext\\core\\Classes\\Core\\Bootstrap.php(109): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager->getCache('cache_core')\n#1 C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.php(24): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Core\\Bootstrap::init(Object(Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader))\n#2 C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\index.php(25): {closure}()\n#3 {main}"}
```

My understandimg is, that "cache_Core" should be replaced by "core", but why is trying to access "cache_core"?

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a file cache problem. Try to manually delete the cache folders first on: typo3temp/var/cache and if this is not working, delete the var/cache folder.
Or if you found (after a month) an other solution (Hopefully) please post it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After I removed typo3temp completely and created a fresh empty typo3temp and (this seems to be the crucial step -> ) I deleted all the old typo3_src-9.x.x.

Although there where no symlinks for these old sources it  does the trick.

Hope it's also helpfully for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Actually deleting (or renaming) the old typo3_src-9.x.x. is the solution, although the symlink already points to the new source code. Very strange!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).